# Issue finding elements using Selenium::Remote::Driver in Perl

Tags: perl, selenium

As part of a test scrip I have to redirect to a 3rd party hosted payment page.  However, when I try and find the input box elements it errors slightly differently depending on which call I try:

```
$driver->find_element_by_id("card.billingAddress.houseNumberOrName")->clear
```

returns "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"

```
$driver->find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="card.billingAddress.houseNumberOrName"')->clear
```

returns "SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression."

The source of the section I am searching  is:

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="2"><div class="fieldSubHeader">Billing Address</div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><div id="idAddress1_card" style="display:inline">Address 1</div>
       <div id="idHouseNumberOrName_card" style="display:none">House Number/Name
   </div</td>
   <td><div class="fieldDiv" id="idDivAddress1_card">
       <input type="text" class="inputField" id="card.billingAddress.houseNumberOrName"   name="card.billingAddress.houseNumberOrName"  value="" size="15" maxlength="40" />
   </div></td>
</tr>
```

Is it the . in the ID that is causing the issue?

(I have checked the computed CSS and it is not hidden!)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing `]`. Replace:

```
'//input[@id="card.billingAddress.houseNumberOrName"'
```

with:

```
'//input[@id="card.billingAddress.houseNumberOrName"]'
                                               HERE ^
```

---

Note that you might simplify it by switching directly to the `find_element_by_id()` method.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the little typo! :) I now get the same as when I use $driver->find_element_by_id("card.billingAddress.houseNumberOrName")->clear which is "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" Any ideas on why that doesn't work?

Comment: @Whirlybird could you please make sure there are no other elements with the same ID on the page?

Comment: That is correct, the only thing is that the name and id properties of the input tag are both identical

Comment: @Whirlybird okay, so there is only one element with this `id`. Are you sure the element is actually visible - can you see it displayed during the test run?

Comment: Unfortunately, due to limitations with my setup, I can't view the test as it happens, but I can directly replicate the test in a browser window, and can see, using inspect element in Chrome, that the computed style should render it visible : -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-background-composite: source-over;
-webkit-mask-repeat: repeat;
-webkit-user-modify: read-only;
-webkit-user-select: text;

display: inline-block;
visibility: visible;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;

Comment: @Whirlybird got it, are you using some sort of a headless setup?..also, you may try waiting for an element to become visible (could be that the element is not becoming visible right away)..

Comment: Yes, ssh access only to the test environment.  Local boxes & network are too locked down.  I have built in a 20 second retry loop, but it still isn't there.  I am pretty certain that it is to do with the dots in the middle of the name/id values, as the same approach works fine on the pages that I own.  I was just hoping someone might of had experience testing Barclaycard Smartpay payment pages with Selenium and point me in the right direction